# Can I branch a 20A heating circuit to add a new outlet?

Tags: electrical

I need a 20 amp outlet in a 2nd storey room.  I currently have 20 amp wire up there to a thermostat (for in ceiling thermal heat).  Can I run a wire from the thermostat to my new outlet?

Comment: How many watts of heat are on this circuit?

Comment: What is the purpose of the 20A circuit in your bedroom?

Comment: There were 3 thermostats on this 20A circuit for the in-ceiling radiant heat.  2 have been disconnected as I switched from electric to a boiler system.  There is one thermostat upstairs in a very tiny bedroom.  So I’m assuming (perhaps not correctly) that 3840/3=1280 each thermostat.  I am putting in an infrared sauna in that bedroom and it requires 2250 watts.  So 1280 + 2250 = 3530 watts.  I’m thinking that should be ok then?

Comment: if 240v it's just under 15 amps so it should be ok. I would want to verify the draw of the connected heat cable so you are not assuming as we don't know where you came up with the 3840.

Comment: That's a good question, I'd like to know the source of the 3840W. Is it known that the old radiant heat units were all the same size?  *Of course you realize, these radiant heat units will be 240V.  That won't help you if you want a 120V outlet.*